# Update an internal document and a field in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm wondering if it's not possible to use update on two elements in the same query.  I have this...

```
db.types.update({"user_id": "aaaawa", "type": "type d"}, {"$set": {"days.7/21/18": {"check": .955}}, {"last_date": new ISODate("2018-07-22)}})
```

which returns an invalid property id. But if I do them as separate updates they work...updating internal document...

```
db.types.update({"user_id": "aaaawa", "type": "type d"}, {"$set": {"days.7/21/18": {"check": .955}}})
```

updating field...

```
db.types.update({"user_id": "aaaawa", "type": "type d"}, {"$set": {"last_date": new ISODate("2018-07-22)}})
```

Comment: You are passing your `last_date` field in next parameter of the query... you need to put it inside `$set` like `db.types.update(
 { "user_id": "aaaawa", "type": "type d" },
 { "$set": { "days.7/21/18": { "check": .955 }, "last_date": new ISODate("2018-07-22") }}
)`

Comment: oh I see it now...thanks!